# fs.writeFile refreshing index.html whenever called

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fs

I have an issue where I am writing data from an array to a JSON file every 10 secs on an express server, and this is causing the main page to reload whenever the writeFile function is called.

The main page makes a GET request to retrieve Entry objects in the array, however I don't understand why it is reloading when the array isn't being changed in anyway, it is just being used to write to the JSON file.

In index.js (server code):

```
const server = require('./app');
const { readFromFile, writeToFile } = require('./helpers/readWrite');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
readFromFile();

// start the server
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
  // set the server to save to file every 10 seconds
  setInterval(writeToFile, 10000);
});
```

In readWrite.js:

```
const Entry = require('../models/entry'); // file containing array that the data is written from.

function writeToFile() {
    const entriesDataStringified = JSON.stringify(Entry.all); // stringify the entriesData array

    // write to the json file, overwriting any data already in the file
    fs.writeFile('./data/entries.json', entriesDataStringified, (err) => {
        // check for error when writing file
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('File successfully written');
        }
    });
}
```

Retrieving entries on client side:

```
async function getPosts(e) {
    try{
        response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/search/page/${pageNum}`);
        data = await response.json();
        console.log(data)
        data.entries.forEach(post => {
            if(!postArray.includes(post)){
                newestArray.push(post);
                postArray.push(post);
                emojiArray.push({id: post.id, emojis: {loveCount: false, laughCount: false, likeCount: false}})
            };
        });
        console.log(emojiArray);
        Post.drawAll();
        pageNum++
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Main page = ???

Comment: I believe it is reloading due to the file change, causing the live server to automatically refresh the page. Going to deploy the client and server code separately to see if this will fix the issue. **fixed. file change was causing automatic reload**