# Node.js `writeFile` And `writeFileSync` In Express.js Route Handler Triggers A Page Reload In Front-End

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node.js-fs

I'm having a problem with my code where the page reloads when fetching to my backend app. My backend app uses `fs` module functions, particularly `writeFile`/`writeFileSync`. When I remove the function calls, everything works perfectly and page doesn't reload.

Frontend code (all in one HTML file for convenience):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="func()">Press me</button> 
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script>
      function func() {
        const output = document.getElementById("output");

        fetch("http://localhost:3000/")
          .then((res) => res.json());
          .then((data) => {
            output.textContent = data.message;
          });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Backend code (Node.js and Express):

```js
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // Deal with CORS
  fs.writeFileSync("hello.txt", "hello world"); // <-- HERE
  res.json({ message: "Hello World" });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

The problem is the page reloads when I click "Press me".

When I removed the fs.writeFileSync line, it works and doesn't reload, everything works perfectly. I also tried with `fs.writeFile` and it doesn't work, even with an empty callback.

I tested with a `setTimeout` to see if the delay was the problem, but page didn't reload and worked as expected.

**My Question is**: Do `fs` functions in (Express) route handlers cause the page to reload in the front-end? And if they are, how to overcome it? What can possibly happen in the backend that can cause a page reload?

What I tried:

- Searched the Internet, nothing is related to my problem.

**There is nothing in the log output of the server, no errors, no warnings**

**Edit**: I tried with `readFile` and `readFileSync`, no page reload. So the problem might be in `writeFile` and `writeFileSync` only.

**Edit**: After some searching, I found that `rm` and `rmSync` also have the same problem. From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70096850/fs-writefile-refreshing-index-html-whenever-called), I found that file change was causing automatic reload, I still don't know how to fix it though.

**Fixed**: Live Server extension was doing this due to change in file system, not a problem with my code.

Comment: Will your files be written as expected? What's in the log output of your express application?

Comment: Nothing in the log output. All clean. If there was anything I would've written it in the post. Anyways, I'll update the question.

Comment: Voting to close as the actual cause described in the answer is in my opinion not really going to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Live Server extension was doing this automatic page reload due to change in file system, not a problem with my code.

You can write a simple web server yourself to serve the pages. Or you can find a workaround by changing the vscode workspace or configuring the live server extension or something like that.